# App Beta iOS com TestFlight

Tags: ios, apple

Estou enviado a primeira versão de uma `app` para a `Apple Store`, porém, ante de enviar para produção, vou disponibilizar primeiro para `Beta Testers`.

Atualmente, o status para `External Testing` está:

> Waiting for Beta App Review

E o status para  `Apple Store` é:

> Prepare for Submission

Minhas dúvidas são:

1. Preciso submeter para `Apple Store` para liberar a versão beta?
2. A análise de versão beta é tão rigorosa quanto a versão de produção (`Apple Store`)?
3. O período de aprovação é o mesmo para Beta e Produção?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Preciso submeter para Apple Store para liberar a versão beta?

Não é necessário, são dois processos distintos, pois você vai querer realmente testar antes de enviar uma versão final para a loja. Então você pode submeter para teste quantas vezes forem necessárias antes de enviar uma versão final.

> A análise de versão beta é tão rigorosa quanto a versão de produção
>   (Apple Store)?

O rigor é o mesmo, uma vez que a versão para **TestFlight** deve seguir o [mesmo *guideline* de revisão](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#testflight). Mas neste caso, você pode explicitamente indicar que é uma versão beta, demo, teste e etc. Em uma versão de produção, se alguma destas indicações estiverem no seu aplicativo, ele será rejeitado.

> O período de aprovação é o mesmo para Beta e Produção?

O período de aprovação é mais curto, em torno de **48 horas** e uma versão de teste fica disponível por **30 dias**.

Lembrando que existem duas formas de realizar estes testes:

- Para usuários **internos** você não precisa submeter para revisão beta, estes são os usuários do *iTunnes Connect*, que tem qualquer umas das 3 permissões de acesso ao seu aplicativo. Até 25 usuários.
- Os usuários **externos** são aqueles que não fazem parte do seu time e não tem acesso ao *iTunes Connect*. Até 1000 usuários.

Para ambos os casos, você precisa cadastrá-los previamente e eles receberam um email para ativar a primeira vez. A partir daí, o próprio aplicativo **TestFlight** irá notificando a cada nova versão.